# Continuity of the addition of arbitrary functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Problem: If each of *f* and *g* is a function, x is a point in the domain of each of *f* and *g*, *f* is continuous at the point (x,*f*(x)),  *g* is continuous at the point (x,*g*)), and *h* = *f* + *g* , then *h* is continuous at the point (x,*h*)).

Proof:

Let *f* and *g* be functions such that x is a point in the domain of each of *f* and *g*

Let *f* be continuous at the point (x,*f*(x))

Let *g* be continuous at the point (x,*g*))

Let S=(A,B) be an arbitrary open interval containing *f*(x) + *g*(x)

Where would I go from here? I am using the definition "the statement *f* is continuous at the point (x,y) means that 1). p is a point on *f*, and 2). if S is **any** open interval containing the number *f*(x), then there is an open interval T containing the number x such that if t is an element of T, and t is in the domain of f, then *f*(t) is an element of S"

Comment: You have not specified the domain and range. The sum f+g needs to be defined so the domain and range are not arbitrary sets.

Answer (score 0):

You just use your definition, but you must think a bit first. If you consider the range of the mentioned interval $T$ it would be in an interval, but the image of the sum potentially can extend to the double interval.

To overcome this you just cut the interval in half. Suppose you have the interval $$S=(f(x)+g(h)-a, f(x)+g(x)+b)$$

Then you construct the intervals

$$S_f=(f(x)-a/2, f(x)+b/2)$$
$$S_g=(g(x)-a/2, g(x)+b/2)$$

and by definition you have intervals $T_f$ and $T_g$ around $x$ such that $f(T_f)\subseteq S_f$ and $g(T_g)\subseteq S_t$. Taking the intersection of these you get an interval $T=T_f\cap T_g$ around $x$. Then you only have to realize that $(f+g)(T)\subset S$.